# How to emulate Attribute Converter in JPA <= 2.0?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, jpa-2.0

JPA 2.1 introduced a nice new feature [Attribute Converter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/AttributeConverter.html) - see an article e.g. here: http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter/

It allows you to have an attribute of a certain type and store it as something else in the database column. E.g. you have an entity with a field color which is of a type `java.awt.Color` but you want it to be stored in the database as a `String`, such as `RED` or `WHITE`.

```
@Entity
class Tag {
    String name;
    java.awt.Color color; // I want it to be stored as a different type
}
```

Is there a way of obtaining the similar result in **JPA <= 2.0**? I want to do it for a type which is **not** an `enum`.

We do not distinguish between the business domain layer and the `@Entity` classes. Of course I can imagine many working solutions if there were some kind of mapping between them. What I am searching for is a solution where we use *directly* the `@Entity` classes themselves in the business domain layer.

Comment: In system which i was working while ago, they serialized class and deserialize field each time before use.

Comment: @user902383, could you be more specific? I use the `@Entity` classes directly as the domain classes. I can imagine a million solutions if the domain classes were distinct from the `@Entity` classes.

Comment: Implementation dependent. Some had "type converters" way back when. You dont mention what is your implementation

Comment: @NeilStockton, I prefer an implementation-agnostic solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I suggest is making this column `@Transient` and add another `@Column` that will be the String value of the `awt.Color`, use getters and setters as the converters.

Your class will be as this:

```
@Transient
java.awt.Color color;
@Column
String colorField;
```

Every time you use your Color use the setter, this setter will decode the color and add this to the colorField field.

```
public setColor(java.awt.Color color){
  this.colorField = color.toString();
  this.color = color;
}
```

Comment: just a tiny comment, you dont need transient field `color` just create transient setter and getter where you automatically do conversion

Comment: Hope that answer will be found googling by people having trouble with TomEE.

Answer (score 1):

As i mention in comment, in system which I was working, custom non-entity class was serialized to byte array and put to db as blob, and deserialize before use.

field was mapped as:

```
 @Column(name = "data")
 private byte[] data;
```

then we had util class with two static methods

```
public static byte[] serialize(Object object) throws IOException,
            ClassNotFoundException {
        // Serialize to a byte array
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        out.writeObject(object);
        out.close();

        // Get the bytes of the serialized object
        byte[] buf = bos.toByteArray();
        return buf;
    }

    public static Object deserialize(byte[] data) throws IOException,
            ClassNotFoundException {
        // Deserialize from a byte array
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(
                data));
        Object o = in.readObject();
        in.close();
        return o;
    }
```

now you could create transient getter and setter and use derialize and deserialize do translate from and to your class

not sure is it recommended solution, but this is copied straight from existing system

Comment: Interesting solution, although it is not exactly what I want - I do not need to store the content of the object, but rather to convert it. However you deserve my plus-one point :) Anyway, it is more or less the same as Koitoer mentioned, just more specific. The key idea for me here is to use the `@Transient` field for the mapping.

Comment: sorry then, i misunderstood you, it is all depends what kind of object you want to store/convert maybe you could do something with enums and `Enumerated` annotation or go with that what  Koitoer suggest.